# I have no idea why im getting a "undefined is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, undefined

So i have no idea why, on line 35, im getting this error, could some one please explain why this is not working, as i cant seem to figure out why?

this is the link to the webpage its uploaded on, you can see the error message in the console, as well as all the code. http://matthew-hoyle.co.uk/files/beta/projects/platformer.php

```
window.onload = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width  = 800;
canvas.height = 600;

function Player() {
    this.width = 20;
    this.height = 20;
    this.color = "red";
    this.posY = (canvas.height / 2) - (this.height / 2);
    this.posX = (canvas.width / 2) - (this.width / 2);
    this.volY = 0;
    this.volX = 0;
    this.gravity = 0.5;
    this.onGround = true;
    this.draw = function() {this.posY += this.volY;
        this.posX += this.volX;
        this.volY += this.gravity;

        c.fillStyle = this.color;
        c.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, this.width, this.height);
    };
}

function Obstacle(x,y,w,h,c) {
    this.posY = y;
    this.posX = x;
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    this.color = c;
    this.draw = function() {
        c.fillStyle = this.color;
        c.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, this.width, this.height);
    };
}

//objects
var player = new Player();
var ground = new Obstacle(0, canvas.height-20,canvas.width,20,"red");

//game update loop
window.setInterval(function() {
    //clears screen
    c.fillStyle = "lightblue";
    c.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //drawing objects
    player.draw();
    ground.draw();
}, 30);
```

};

Comment: Would you mind pointing out in your code where the problem is?

Comment: Reproduction case: `x = undefined; x()`. So find out (*using the debugger and inspecting the stack trace / full error message*) which expression was undefined and was incorrectly attempted to be invoked as a function. Then fix it, such that it is not undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var ground = new Obstacle(0, canvas.height-20,canvas.width,20,"red");
```

Here you initialize `ground` as an `Obstacle` with 5 parameters. The fifth, `c`, is the string `"red"`. So, when later on you call `ground.draw()` you're trying to invoke `"red".fillRect`, and that's not a valid member function of a string.

The underlying problem is that the parameter `c` of the `Obstacle` constructor hides the global `c` variable because it is a closer scope, therefore hiding the canvas context reference you intend to use.